# Биты. Позиции

Tags: c++

Я сижу и думаю, думаю и сижу, но не могу понять, почему в этом коде первым берется 7 бит, и почему он работает.

```
unsigned int gu(unsigned char *buf, int pos, int len){
    unsigned int bits=0;
    int i;
    for(i=pos; i<pos+len; i++) bits=(bits<<1)+((buf[i/8]>>(7-i%8))&1u);
    return bits;
}
```

Этот код возвращает данные из строки buf начиная от бита pos, длинной len бит.

Мне казалось, что первым идет нулевой бит, а тут берется 7. Код из другого проекта прекрасно работает в этом. Хочется верить, что это сумасшедший проект, а не я.

UPD. Подозреваю, что это такой широко распространенный формат кодирования с вот такой позицией бит.

Comment: Зачем писать код в одну строку и без пробелов?

Comment: Если код понятен, можно не тратиться на украшения.

Answer (score 2):

> Мне казалось, что первым идет нулевой бит, а тут берется 7. Код из другого проекта прекрасно работает в этом. Хочется верить, что это сумасшедший проект, а не я.
>
> UPD. Подозреваю, что это такой широко распространенный формат кодирования с вот такой позицией бит.

Я ничего тут особенного не вижу.

В цикле производится перебор `len` бит. Каждый очередной бит записывается в младший бит буфера `bits`, который предварительно сдвигается влево на бит. `buf[i/8]` - дает октет, в котором находится очередной бит. Правый сдвиг этого октета на `7 - i % 8` позволяет нам видеть этот бит самым младшим, чтобы впоследствие снять его единичной маской.

**`7`** тут именно для того, чтобы сдвинуть бит **на нулевую позицию**, иначе это выражение всегда будет сдвигать весь остаток вправо, за границу октета.

В октете `8` бит, `i % 8` - это позиция самого бита, если считать справа, а `8 - i % 8` - это число бит слева от этой позиции, т.е. включая сам бит. Вот чтобы его исключить и нужно `7`, а не `8`.

> Вот чтобы его исключить и нужно `7`, а не `8`

Вот только не справа, а слева!
Чтобы сдвинуть бит под единичную маску вправо нужно `i % 8`, а не `7 - i % 8`. Для `7 - i % 8` нужна маска `0x80` и сдвиг влево.

Думаю, здесь ошибка!
С нормальным порядком бит (от младшего к старшему) этот код будет неправильно возвращать значение битового поля. Здесь считается, что биты в каждом байте идут в обратном порядке, поэтому, если не смешивать методы, ошибку видно не будет.

Comment: Чтобы метод был корректным для нормального порядка бит, `7-i%8` нужно заменить на `i%8`.

Comment: Только тут очевидно важно, чтобы и "упаковщик" и "распаковщик" действовали по одному алгоритму.

Comment: угу

>не смешивать методы